# Trouble on uninstalling RVM

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, uninstallation

I am running Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid and I was probably wrong to uninstall RVM and now it seams to be not completely removed from the system. Now I would like to install that again but I am in trouble.

What happens is that I have strange outputs generated when I try to execute some command lines:

```
# Note that following command lines don't output the version
# (between the word "version" and the word "is") as it should be.

$ rvm
$ rvm -v
> -bash: /usr/local/rvm/scripts/base: No such file or directory
> A RVM version  is installed yet 1.10.3 is loaded.
>  Please do one of the following:
>   * 'rvm reload'
>   * open a new shell


# Even if I use the 'cd' command I have problems...

$ cd ..
> -bash: /usr/local/rvm/scripts/initialize: No such file or directory
> -bash: /usr/local/rvm/scripts/hook: No such file or directory
```

That probably means that RVM is not correctly removed even if Ruby seams to be running as well:

```
$ which ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [i686-linux]
```

So, **what I can do to completely remove/uninstall RVM?**

---

**UPDATE**

I solved part of the problem (or, maybe, all problems): that (those) was related to Phusion Passenger that was still loading the old path related to the Ruby version managed by RVM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
RVM installs everything into ~/.rvm. To remove RVM from your system run 'rm -rf ~/.rvm'.
```

Refer [this](http://www.mkoby.com/2011/06/03/completely-removing-rvm/). and [where is everything installed to?](http://beginrescueend.com/support/faq/)

Comment: That folder there isn't on my system (maybe because I am running Ubuntu).

Comment: run the command "rvm info" from your terminal to locate the PATH and see where rvm is installed.

Comment: @ - So, I have this `environment: PATH: "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/rvm/bin"`. Now, how can I remove RVM?

Comment: rvm is not installed properly. Try restarting system and reinstalling rvm. Will help if you put your rvm list and rvm info here.

Answer (score 9):

first try `echo $rvm_path` - if that shows anything - `rm -rf` it

second:

```
sudo rm -rf /ust/local/rvm /etc/rvmrc /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh ~/.rvm*
```

next check `ls -l /usr/local/bin | grep rvm` this will show links to rvm - `rm -rf` them

and last `which rvm` - if it shows anything try to check this path and remove at least this file.

Comment: +1 for /etc/rvmrc, and I had to logout and login the user to make the  `cd` messages (see OP) go away.

Answer (score 1):

From `rvm help`:

```
implode  - (seppuku) removes the rvm installation completely.
           This means everything in $rvm_path (~/.rvm || /usr/local/rvm).
           This does not touch your profiles. However, this means that you
           must manually clean up your profiles and remove the lines which source RVM.
```

Judging from your `$PATH` you can also (alternatively) remove all of the following files and directories:

- `/usr/local/rvm`
- `/etc/rvmrc`
- `/etc/profile.d/rvm.sh`